# BeautifulSoup 'AttributeError'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'" when I run the following. however, when the same tasks are performed on a block string variable; it works.

Any Ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib        import urlopen

url = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Albert%20Einstein&explaintext")

print ((BeautifulSoup(((urlopen(url)).read()))).find('extract').string).split("\n", 1)[0]
```

Comment: So many parenthesis... my eyes hurt. You really need to read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
url = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Albert%20Einstein&explaintext")

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
print soup.find('extract')  # returns None
```

The find method is not finding anything with the tag 'extract'. If you want to see it work then give it a HTML tag that exists in the document like 'pre' or 'html'

'extract' looks like an xml tag. You might want to try reading the BeautifulSoup documentation on parsing XML - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing XML. Also there is a new version of BeautifulSoup out there (bs4). I find the API much nicer.